# Need help with small circuit to convert signal to audio

Tags: circuit-design, speakers, sound

I'm an engineer but not an electrical engineer, so I have a basic understanding of electronics, but no serious experience... I am going to buy an EMG kit [here](https://www.sparkfun.com/products/retired/11776), but I want to connect the output to a speaker, so I can hear (hopefully) when the muscle will contract/relax. Where can I get help on putting together whatever is needed for that sound output?

Comment: That's not what that kit does.  The kit outputs a DC voltage level relative to the electrical activity of the muscle.  DC voltages do not have a "sound", they have no frequency by definition.

Comment: Electronically speaking, it looks like you can use the sensor output, which varies in proportion to the muscle contraction, to modulate an oscillator to get a varying pitch and drive a speaker, which is straightforward enough. Practically speaking, you could well be be able to buy a circuit module to do this as there's lots of Lego-like boards out there these days. But I haven't the opportunity to look for you. Search the interweb for a voltage controlled oscillator board/module and see what's out there.

Comment: @ChrisM. - See TonyM's comment - I do want to translate the voltage level into a frequency change so I can hear it. Hence the additional electronic guidance I need. I didn't expect the signal to come out of the sensor with a frequency by itself.

Comment: @Frank Fair enough, it wasn't clear (to me) what you expected from the kit.  As TonyM said, VCO (voltage controlled oscillator) is probably your best bet, although it will just be a tone.

Comment: @ChrisM. But the tone would change depending on the voltage output by the kit, right?

Comment: Yes, the frequency of the oscillator's output is controlled by the DC signal output from the kit.  I just mean that it won't sound like the muscle actually contracting (like you hear with a stethoscope)

Comment: Good enough! :-) (I don't think you can hear muscle contraction with a stethoscope :-)

Comment: Probably not, that's not my area of expertise.

Comment: @Frank Please clarify your problem by editing the question itself, don't just leave a comment. Right now it reads as if you plan to contract your muscles at sonic frequencies.

Answer (score 1):

The problem with this kit is that the output is a DC voltage. If you directly connect the output to the speaker, you wont hear anything..

To hear something, you have to go through several step :

- Transform the kit output from DC voltage to a sinus like waveform. The frequency of that signal has to be related to the kit output voltage level to hear a difference.
- Amplify that waveform and adapt it considering the speaker inner resistance

Since you are not familiar with electronic, I suggest you to take a look at some arduino tutorial. If you combine some of them, you will be able to reach your goal.

Comment: I understand that - I'm precisely looking for detailed instructions, plans, lists of components ... to do that. I wouldn't be able to make a circuit to convert DC voltage to a sine waveform then amplify it myself :-)

Comment: We won't do the system design for you. We can answer to precise question about a part of a subsystem but you have to try something by yourself

Comment: Do I need to buy something like that: https://www.digikey.com/products/en/crystals-oscillators-resonators/vcos-voltage-controlled-oscillators/173?

Comment: Also, note that my question was: "where can I get help..." - so I would be more than happy if somebody here could recommend a place like a TechShop in the Bay Area where I could go find more help.

Comment: If you are not familiar with electronic, I suggest you to follow some arduino tutorial. You want to take a look at ADC, DAC and signal amplification. You can find here the DAC and amplifying part with arduino : https://www.arduino.cc/en/Tutorial/SimpleAudioPlayer

Comment: Is an Arduino required for such a "simple" project?

Comment: There is other way than using a microcontroller but it will require larger electronic knowledge

Comment: There is plenty of tutorial and a very active community, I'm confidente of your success :) If you have question or issue with arduino, you can post your question [here](https://arduino.stackexchange.com/)

Comment: This should get you started:
https://mechatrofice.com/arduino/arduino-voltage-controlled-oscillator-vco

Only instead of using a potentiometer to control the input voltage, you'll wire it to your EMG kit,

Comment: With these two tutorials, you can get your project done ^^

Comment: you are welcome. You will see that you can do lots of thing with no much effort with arduino, I'm sure you'll enjoy it ;)